# change color for part of function answer while color depends on word

Tags: string, excel, colors, excel-2010, vba

change color for part of function answer while color depends on word
for example: today you won 100$
so the part "won 100$" (or won 58$ - depends on calculation) must be green
and if the string is:
today you loosed 39$
"loosed 39$" must be in red
I've found a [single color solution](http://www.knowexcel.com/view/1403770-color-and-bold-single-text-strings-within-cell.html), but doesn't answer my question
maybe you guys could help me?
thanks in advance

Comment: Function's output can be single value or an array. In your case, I suggest you to output data into a hidden sheet/range and then copy the values and format accordingly. But this depends on how much of data you plan to process. Number of times you will call this function. Speed of calculations. Not to mention the weight on formatting.

Comment: In your case, even conditional formatting doesn't seem to be an aid. If you are not happy with hiding stuff. You may simply run another sub to format cell values in the sheet after function has returned the "won" statement. Hopefully all these going to happen at false screen updating.. In this second function you could simply include an array of rules to be applied on formatting.

Answer (score 0):

A **function** in Excel can only return a value, it cannot perform color formatting.  You would need to **Copy** the cell and **PasteSpecial Values** back into the cell.  Then you can color format parts of the text string.